# Add Polyfill support if project not created with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular

I have taken over an Angular 7 application that I did not design.

I have a web page that requests the user's date of birth as one of the fields, using the following code in a **signup.component.html** file:

`<input [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" id="DOB" name="dateOfBirth" type="date" max="9999-12-31" />`

The above works in Windows 10 Chrome & Firefox (have not yet had a chance to test Edge).

However, IE 11 reports the following **error** in the debugger console:

> (X) SCRIPT438: Object doesn't have support property or method
>   'matches' main-client.js (xxxxxx,yy)

I have isolated the issue to the DOB, because if the Angular two-way binding above, `[(ngModel)]`, is removed, the application does not give the error in IE 11.

After researching, this seems to be a common problem if `polyfill` support is not enabled for the Angular application.  Most solutions describe fixes if Angular-CLI was used to create the necessary files that need to be modified.

However, the application source code has `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `tsconfig.json`, but does not have the following files:
`angular.json`, `tsconfig.app.json`, `tsconfig.spec.json`, or the `\src\polyfill.ts`

**My question is:**

How do I add polyfill support to this application?

Comment: This may help you: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills-for-non-cli-users

Comment: Thank you.  Have you used this solution?  I am still unclear on how to use this solution. Do I add the text indicated in the src/index.html to the beginning of my signup.component.html?  Do I also have to add it to my app.component.html?  If so, should I be able to enter the date in the mm/dd/yyyy format into IE, similar to Chrome and Firefox and Edge?  It seems that I have a dependency missing.     For now, I have added a unique label to the Date of Birth entry box for the user to enter the date in yyyy-mm-dd format, if using IE.

Answer (score 0):

To add polyfills to your angular project manually just add them to your app `index.html` in root of your folder, like:
`src/index.html`

However for your issue it seems that you can do this to support IE 9+

```js
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
                              Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}
```

from [Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)